# Script no ubica el cursor en la celda A2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo este script que uso para ciertas tareas que tengo, el script trabaja perfectamente pero quisiera que al final, este dejara el cursor en la celda **A2**. Tengo otro script que hace esto, pero no logro "combinarlos"; de forma separada trabajan perfectamente.

El script que dejar el cursor en **A2** se ha combinado bien con otros scripts pero por alguna razón no logro hacerlo funcionar con este en particular, quisiera entender el error.

Este es el script que uso:

```
function bodega() {
   var s, data, ubcns, i, rw;


s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ubcns=s.getDataRange().getValues();
  ubcns.shift();
  // los datos que hemos de distribuir
  data=ubcns.shift();
  //solamente la primera columna
  ubcns=ubcns.map(function(x) {return x[0];});
  //quita las filas antes de 10
  for (i in [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) ubcns.shift();
  //fila de la ubicacion
  rw=ubcns.indexOf(data[0])+10;
  //poner datos
  s.getRange(rw, 2, 1, 15).setValues([data.slice(1)]);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Scan');
  var rangesToClear = ['A2:C2'];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();


    }

}
```

Este es el script que intento incorporar, o al menos las lineas necesarias. Independiente uno del otro funcionan bien.

```
function mypos() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Scan");
    var cell = sheet.setActiveSelection("A2"); //getRange("A2");
    cell.activate();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que la hoja de cálculo tiene una hoja llamada "Scan" y que la celda a activar A2 corresponde a esa hoja, simplemente llama la función `mypos()` al final de tu función `bodega()`

Notas:

1. En el editor de Google Apps Script en App Maker, Google ha integrado el uso de [JSHint](https://jshint.com/docs/#inline-configuration) y este sugiere que las funciones se declaren antes de ser llamadas, motivo por el cual estoy pasando `mypos()` al inicio.
2. `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` sólo se require cuando se ha modificado una hoja de cálculo y se requiere que el script tome los resultados de esas modificaciones. Considerando que todos los camibos se pendientes de aplicar se aplican al terminar la ejecución, no tiene sentido incluirlo al final.

```
function mypos() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Scan");
    var cell = sheet.setActiveSelection("A2"); //getRange("A2");
    cell.activate();
    // La siguiente línea no se requiere.
    //SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

}

function bodega() {
   var s, data, ubcns, i, rw;


s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ubcns=s.getDataRange().getValues();
  ubcns.shift();
  // los datos que hemos de distribuir
  data=ubcns.shift();
  //solamente la primera columna
  ubcns=ubcns.map(function(x) {return x[0];});
  //quita las filas antes de 10
  for (i in [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) ubcns.shift();
  //fila de la ubicacion
  rw=ubcns.indexOf(data[0])+10;
  //poner datos
  s.getRange(rw, 2, 1, 15).setValues([data.slice(1)]);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Scan');
  var rangesToClear = ['A2:C2'];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) { 
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();


    }
// Llamamos la función mypos();
mypos();

}
```